# Error installing library of Scrapy in PyCharm

Tags: scrapy, pycharm

I can install other packages, but can't install Scrapy. I get the following errors:

```
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

running build_ext
building 'lxml.etree' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).
```

However, C++ is installed, which I installed numerous of times. I have x86 and 64 bit installations (not sure if it's 10.0) but I have 2013-2017 versions installed. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade your pip by following command.

python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Then install Scrapy by following command.

pip install Scrapy

Answer (score 0):

download latest twisted package and install with pip.
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted

after that install scrapy

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found that pywin32 was not installed...
So I did

Answer (score 0):

download the latest **Twisted** package from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted)

You want to use the amd64 if you have Windows 64 (regardless if it's an Intel processor or not)

You can use any browser for the download and copy/paste the file into the project folder of your current pycharm project.

Then in pycharm type this:

```
pip install Twisted-20.3.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
```

(assuming that your package was Twisted-20.3.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl)
then proceed with:

```
pip install Scrapy
```